# ActionMailer in rails makes every page of app hang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to send mail using the :mail function built into Rails 3 like this:

```
  default from: "Me <me@myname.mailgun.org>"

  def gift
      mail :to => "myname@gmail.com", :subject => "test"
  end
```

Then I have a file called setup_mail.rb in `config/initializers`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_charset = "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       :authentication => :plain,
       :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
       :port => 587,
       :domain => "myname.mailgun.org",
       :user_name => "postmaster@myname.mailgun.org",
       :password => "mypass"
  }
}
```

I added that code then restarted my server, but the app loads indefinitely.

Comment: Does it work if you use this instead: `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail` and define the config for sendmail like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3386332/445131

Comment: If I follow that thread and make the changes, it just says "connection refused". It seems as though action mailer doesnt even work if I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing `config.action_mailer` from within an initializer. Remove the wrapping `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` block and just change all `config.action_mailer` entries to `ActionMailer::Base`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :authentication => :plain,
  :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "myname.mailgun.org",
  :user_name => "postmaster@myname.mailgun.org",
  :password => "mypass"
}
```

Comment: Done. Restarted server, still hangs. The app loads if I delete setup_mail.rb.